# Get country level Geometries from GADM

Tags: java, geotools

I'm using geotools to open [gadm36.shp from gadm.org](https://gadm.org/download_world.html) which shapefile containing worldwide administrative areas. I'm trying to get a single Geometry (e.g. org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPolygon) for each country.  So if for example, there were 195 countries in this shapefile, I would have 195 Geometries.  As a side note, I also have the GPKG file for the world so if using that is simpler, I'm happy to use that instead.

```
// load collection from shapefile
File file = new File("<PATH>/gadm36.shp");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = source.getFeatures(Filter.INCLUDE);
```

**That last line collection has a size of 339127.  It seems to contain every sate, country, town, village, etc. How do I get a smaller list of just the countries?**

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  I'm at the same spot.  I just want the countries, but the metadata has "republic" and dozens of other variations.

Comment: @Mastiff sortof.  Merging them into a smaller list just made each polygon more complicated and didn't help with lookup take a long time. My solution was to create a quad tree where each tile maps to all the countries that intersect its boundary. Each "Tile" has 4 children tiles [up-right, up-left, lower-right, lower-left] where each child is another instance of the Tile class.  Using a lon/lat to find the country name went from about 5 seconds to about 5 mSec.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I was assuming the initial giant GADM contained thousands of small polygons representing states and counties and who-knows-what.  Sounds like this is not the case, and that the country boundaries themselves are just complex?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Filter.INCLUDE` you need to provide a filter that selects the features that you want. You'll need to play about a bit but if you just want countries then something like ENGTYPE_1 = 'Kingdom' or ENGTYPE_1 = 'Country' might do it.

The easiest way to build a filter is to add the [`gt-cql` module](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/cql/index.html) to your project and use

```
Filter f = ECQL.toFilter("ENGTYPE_1 = 'Kingdom' or ENGTYPE_1 = 'Country'");
FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = source.getFeatures(f);
```

I'd also recommend using the [geopackage](https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/gadm36_gpkg.zip) rather than the shapefile as your filter will be passed to the database and you'll get the features back more quickly.

And as a final style note `URLs.fileToUrl(file)` is preferred over `file.toURI().toURL()` as it handles windows files and spaces much better.

Comment: GADM doesn't contain a ENGTYPE_1 of Country.  Using Kingdom selects all 300+ UK records and a few for Wallis and Futuna. Thanks for the post anyway because I did find it useful.

Comment: I guess there is an attribute that will allow you to filter out the boundaries that you need, but I couldn't find any metadata on GADM.